# CCRenderTexture in cocos2d-x on Android

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, cocos2d-x

I create a `CCRenderTexture` when my game starts and draw something on it. But sometimes when I launch the App, it pauses at the following line in CCRenderTexture.cpp and shows an alert. My app is black, too.

```
CCAssert(glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) == GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE, "Could not attach texture to framebuffer");
```

What is wrong with this? I need help, my cocos2d-x version is 2.1.0. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, I create a CCRenderTexture when game start, it is too early to create it